# recording all the files in a large directory

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, directoryinfo

I've got a number of directories with a large number of files in them (~10,000).  I want to create a list of these files in my app, and have already threaded the io access so that the app doesn't freeze while they load.  However if I exit the app before all files are loaded, the thread doesn't respond to the .Join() until the call to dirInfo.GetFiles(...) is completed:

```
// ... mythread
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach(FileINfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles(extension)) 
    {
        // with large directories, the GetFiles call above 
        //    can stall for a long time
        ...
```

Caching the files out of the foreach just moves the problem.  I need some kind of threaded, callback-y way of finding the files in the directory and I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
tenpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) when your application is about to close (before the *Join*).

```
myThread.Abort();
// Wait for myThread to end.
myThread.Join();
```

Also, you might want to catch the `ThreadAbortException` in the thread method and do some finalization/cleaning, if necessary.

```
try {
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach(FileINfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles(extension)) 
    {
        // with large directories, the GetFiles call above 
        //    can stall for a long time
        ...
    }
}
catch (ThreadAbortException e)
{
    // cleaning
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Thread from the ThreadPool class.  This will make it a background thread and it should receive a ThreadInteruptException when the application closes.

Comment: I think this doesn't solve the problem ... The ThreadInterruptedException only raises when the worker thread enters in WaitSleepJoin state. So, in this case, the Exception could only be thrown when the dirInfo.GetFiles finishes.